# Theming image.html.twig for one paragraph type with custom template suggestion

Tags: theming, hooks, 9

I have a custom module that when installed, creates a paragraph type called "Gallery". Gallery has one field called "field_gallery_images", which is a media reference.

**I am trying to replace `image.html.twig` with `image--gallery.html.twig` only for images inside my gallery.**

I have managed to get Drupal to recognise and load my custom template from the modules template directory. However, every single image on the site now uses this template. **I only want the template to be used for images of my paragraph type** (or it's field). All other images should use the default image.html.twig.

Here is `gallery.module`:

```
function gallery_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
        'image__gallery' => [
      'template' => 'image--gallery',
      'base hook' => 'image',
    ],
  ];
}

function gallery_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
 $suggestions[] = 'image__gallery';
}
```

There is nothing I can test against inside any of the variables passed into both hooks to target my templates scope.

Am I using the wrong hooks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the variables passed by default are not very helpful. The trick is to add an identifier of the field to the image attributes in field preprocessing. See this great answer [How to add attributes to a specific field's image](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257639/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-specific-fields-image/257721#257721)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, helpful to know. I couldn't find a way access the image via `hook_preprocess_field` as images are nested inside media so I had to put a flag inside the media object, then use `hook_preprocess_media` to check for the flag and set an attribute which I could then test against inside `hook_theme_suggestions_image_alter` - not pretty but it works.

Comment: You have to be careful with that, media can be re-used, To avoid that configure a separate media type only used in this media reference field. This media type could simply contain an image field with a unique name or, if you keep the standard name for media images, you can test in field preprocess the bundle name of the parent entity of the field against the media type name.